# Cannot find module 'babel-core' and "@babel-core" is installed

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, installation, babeljs

i get this error when i run `npm run dev`

ERROR in ./src/app.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-core'
Require stack:

even that I installed @babel-core not babel-core

here is my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

and here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-setup-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --mode=development",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false,
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false,
    "net": false,
    "stream": false,
    "tls": false
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^15.12.5",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">3"
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> even that I installed @babel-core not babel-core

`@babel/core` is the one to use, but that only works with `"babel-loader": "^8.x"`, so your `package.json` is currently wrong because it has

```
"babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
```

If you install the newest version you should be good to go.

Comment: i did `npm install babel-loader@8.0.0-beta.0 @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack` and now it's `"babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.0"`  and it gives me now `Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-env'`

Comment: @ZiadAli Why beta? The most recent version is `8.2.2`. That `babel-preset-env` implies that something is referencing `babel-preset-env` (The babel 6.x plugin) instead of `@babel/preset-env` (the babel 7.x plugin). The config in your question wouldn't trigger that so you'll need to look at your files to look for references to that wrong plugin

Comment: you are right, thanks ... i found `env` in my `webpack.config.js`